# Inkjet printer and digital encoder

Tags: sensor, motor

I'm looking at some components of an inkjet

[image]

Does anyone know why it uses an optical encoder on the scroller shaft? Doesn't the shaft rotate by a step whenever the print head reaches the head? Why is there a need for the printer to keep track of the number of mechanical rotations?

Comment: So that it knows if/when something gets jammed ...

Comment: In that case, why don't inkjets use rotary encoders instead of optical ones?

Comment: What do you mean by 'rotary encoders'? Many rotary encoders are optical since they don't wear out over time.

Comment: I mean, quadrature encoders. Those that give gray codes.

Comment: Quadrature encoders don't give grey codes ... They are also often optical (look inside any old 'ball' mouse and you'll find at least 2 of them)

Comment: quadrature encoders are incremental. You are confusing them with absolute ones.

Comment: Oh right. Are there absolute rotary encoders?

Comment: Of course there are. They just more complicated and more expensive, so used only when it is really necessary.

Comment: Absolute encoders are useful when you need to know the shaft angle on power-up without doing a homing routine. For your printer the homing routine will determine the zero position and after that it's just a matter of keeping track of the count.

Comment: @transistor So how do printers with relative encoders perform homing? For instance, if the printer is abruptly powered down, how does it know when the printer is back in the zero position? Probably not with a microswitch right, because then it'd be clicking it each time it reaches the zero position.

Comment: @Kar, with a [slot sensor](http://www.nskelectronics.com/slot_sensor.html). No parts to wear out. If they do use a microswitch it could be a silent type with contacts that wipe rather than toggle.

Answer (score 4):

The printer in your photo uses brushed DC motors, not steppers. You can vary the supply voltage to a DC motor to control its speed, but the actual speed will vary depending on loading so you cannot set the position that way.

Encoders are required because that is the only way the controller can determine the position of the mechanism.

DC motors are used rather than steppers because they are faster, more powerful, more efficient and cheaper.

Comment: Printers seem to run a 'homing' routine on every boot by, probably, resetting the motor to its initial position, how does it actually know where the initial position actually is? The plastic piece only shows lines representing a "step", but wouldn't all steps look the same so the printer wouldn't be able to find the initial position?